# why does "if (file_exists($view_file.$file))" fail in a docker container?

Tags: php, docker

My code is running in a DOCKER container. I check to see if a certain file exists and it fails. But when I run (command line)

```sh
$ docker exec 6adf ls -ls /app/assets/image_crud/views/list.php
```

I get:

```sh
8 -rwxrwxrwx 1 1001 134 5744 Feb 23 06:48 /app/assets/image_crud/views/list.php
```

Which means that the file was found.

My code (in php in the container) is trying to run

```php
if (file_exists("/app/assets/image_crud/views/list.php"))
```

and that fails. I thought maybe it was my path, but now I am not sure anymore. Is this a "docker thing"?

Comment: Fails how? Please show how you are running it and error messages.

Comment: Please share a little more about the docker container(s), too.

Comment: Here is how the container was run from docker-compose php-fpm:
    build: ./php
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: bitnami/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=192.168.122.1"
    networks:
      - net

Comment: Here is the code that is throwing the exception: if (file_exists($view_file.$file))
  {
   $path = $view_file.$file;
   $file_exists = TRUE;
  }

  if ( ! $file_exists)
  {
   throw new Exception('Unable to load the requested file: '.$file, 16);
  }

Comment: In the code in original post, I hard coded in the path just to make it easier to read.

Comment: richb201@richb201-XPS-13-9370:~$ docker inspect --format '{{json .Mounts}}' docker-substantiator_php-fpm_1 | jq .
[
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/opt/docker-substantiator/app",
    "Destination": "/app",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
]

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to format these messages!

Comment: volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
  jasperreports_data:
    driver: local
networks:
  net:

Comment: I am wondering if propagation needs to be set to rshared? I tried adding this line to my docker-compose but it didn't seem to "take" after I restarted the container: bind-propagation: shared